# Removing an edge from a circuit on a connected graph

Tags: graph-theory

> Let $G = (V,E)$ be a connected graph. Suppose $e$ is an edge in a circuit of $G$. Show that the new graph $(V,E-\{e\})$ is still connected.

Attempt: Let $v,w \in V$ be vertices. Then inside $G$, $v$ and $w$ are connected. Suppose the circuit starts and ends at vertex $a \in V$. Then the only problem that could occur is that the deleted edge is part of the connection between $v$ and $w$. So let's suppose this were the case.

I want to use the transitivity of the connected relation to say that $v$ is connected to $a$ which is connected to $v_i$, the vertex of the disconnect, which is connected to $w$. I can do the latter by symmetry of the relation $v$ connected to $w$. However, there is a concern whether $v$ is connected to $a$. Namely that the deleted edge occurring at $v_i$ might also appear in the connection between $v$ and $a$. Can this happen? If so, how can I change my walk to bypass it.

Comment: *Hint*: The problem talks about removing an edge. The vertices that edge connects are not removed.

Comment: Oh sorry, I corrected that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every two vertex of a circuit are connected by two different, non-overlapping paths.

If we take only one edge out, then we are destroying one of those paths. This, we can still reroute paths which involved getting through 2 vertex of the circuit via the other path.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*: If the path from $v$ to $w$ does not contain $e$, we are done. If it does contain $e$, then the path is $v\ldots a b\ldots w$, where $e$ is an edge from $a$ to $b$. But $a$ and $b$ are in a circuit. What does that tell you about the number of ways to get from $a$ to $b$?